# Trouble getting GIMP plugins to work (python attribute missing)

Tags: python, gimp

I'm trying to add some popular plugins to GIMP (version 2.99.10), but when I launch GIMP, I get errors like the following:

```
AttributeError: 'SuperResolution' object has no attribute 'set_translation_domain'
```

SuperResolution is a subclass of Gimp.PlugIn.

I've only installed GIMP recently, so I'm guessing there's some sort of path / scope issue that's causing python not to be able to see the inherited set_translation_domain attribute, but I don't exactly know what the problem would be.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error as well as your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Gimp 2.99 is a development version, the plugin interface is still changing.  Use the exact Gimp version the plugin has been written for or wait for a GimpML version that matches a recent Gimp version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **superresolution.py** replace this:

```py
def do_query_procedures(self):
    self.set_translation_domain(
        "gimp30-python", Gio.file_new_for_path(Gimp.locale_directory())
    )
    return ["superresolution"]
```

To this:

```py
def do_query_procedures(self):
    return ["superresolution"]

def do_set_i18n(self, procname):
    return True, 'gimp30-python', None
```

That happens because they changed how localization works in the recent builds of GIMP (2.99.10 - 2.99.13). Here is one of their internal plugins [foggify](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/blob/master/plug-ins/python/foggify.py) to compare.